# Test functions in the weak form of Poisson equation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

Consider the Poisson equation with zero Dirichlet boundary condition: Find $u \in C^2 (\Omega)\cap C(\overline{\Omega})$ s.t.
$$\begin{cases}
-\Delta u=f&in\ \Omega {,}\\
u\mid _{\partial \Omega }=0,&
\end{cases} $$
where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and $f \in L^2 (\Omega)$. To obtain a weak formulation, one typically multiplies the equation by a test function $\varphi \in C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$, integrates over $\Omega$ by parts and obtains
$$ \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla \varphi dx = \int_{\Omega} f \varphi dx.$$
This makes sense for $u \in H_0^1 (\Omega)$, thus the problem is: Find $u \in H_0^1 (\Omega)$ s.t.
$$ \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla \varphi dx = \int_{\Omega} f \varphi dx$$
for every test function $\varphi \in C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$. As the test functions are dense in $H_0^1 (\Omega)$, one may equivalently write the weak problem as: Find $u \in H_0^1 (\Omega)$ s.t.
$$ \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v dx = \int_{\Omega} f v dx$$
for every $v \in H_0^1 (\Omega)$.

Is there a reason for using smooth functions in the derivation instead of $H_0^1 (\Omega)$? As far as I understand, the derivation makes sense for $H_0^1 (\Omega)$ functions just the same.

Comment: Doing it this way you can avoid talking about traces of Sobolev functions, i.e. the boundary terms that'd pop up in the integration by parts if our functions didn't vanish at the boundary. These boundary values are zero for an $H_0^1$ function, but in testing with smooth compactly supported functions we don't even need to think about them.

Comment: @Jose27 So is it that the divergence theorem is not applicable for Sobolev functions? So integration on the boundary would not make sense as such. In Wiki, divergence theorem is defined for continuously differentiable functions, but I guess Sobolev functions are not necessarily continuously differentiable?

Comment: Divergence theorem is applicable, but how are you going to prove it if not by approximation by smooth functions? (Recall that proving it in the smooth case was already sufficiently challenging if you want a general enough version). Also, there’s the issue of traces mentioned above. No one wants to talk about it unless really necessary, so we often postpone it as much as possible.